# C# DataGridView MouseClick + CTRL not calling CellClick() EventHandler

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm using **WinForms** and a **DataGridView**.
I've register an `CellClick` event for **selecting/unselecting 1 item** (project name).
The problem is that with *CTRL* button hold down + *Mouseclick* 
this Event is not fired.

This is my EventHandler:

```
private void dataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex >= dataGridView.Rows.Count ||
                e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex >= dataGridView.Columns.Count) return;

            if (dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected)
                this.selectedProject = dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as GlobalProject;
            else this.selectedProject = null;

            OnChoose(new OnChooseProjectEventArgs(this.selectedProject != null));            
        }
```

Why is that? And what's the workaround, please

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you unsubscribe to the cellclick event somewhere. Normally the cell click fires even with the CTRL key being held down (I just tried it in a sample proj).

Or maybe you have a global hook in your app (or another control in the form) that catches CTRL key down and handles it somewhere else.